# Load plist in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, plist

i'm just new to iOS Programming, so appreciate for any help. I'm trying to save text from UITextField to plist and load it in UITableView.

I've managed to make the text not overwritten, but when i try to load it in the table,the app crash.

I know the issue is when my table load the Data.plist since it's array in array.

But I still don't have to clue how to load my plist to table.
This is my code when save the text to plist.

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];


    if (nil == array) {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }


    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [list addObject:resi.text];

    [array addObject:list];

    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
```

And this is the whole code for my table view

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [array count];
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
ub;/{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 [detailViewController release];
 */
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
// get paths from root direcory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

[myHistoryTable reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Try this

```
//As you have NSArrays as objects in self.array. 
NSArray *list = (NSArray *)[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if(list && [list count] > 0) { //to check and avoid any crash
    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you..!It works..but additional question, what if I just want to make the list only 10? If there are 11 items, the first item will be replace by the second and so on.